# Lamb ribs - how to cook them

Tags: ribs, lamb

I frequently buy a half or a whole lamb and always get a rack of ribs with this - but I never really know what to do with them.  I've tried roasting them (which does kind of work), and I've tried some of the recipes that you see around for pork ribs which don't seem to work with lamb.

Can anyone give me any suggestions for what to do with them?

Comment: Why don't they "work?"  It will be easier for people to help you if you describe specifically what you've tried and what isn't turning out the way you want.

Comment: There are lots of rack of lamb recipes if you search... why would you start with pork recipes?

Comment: See my profile photo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My local lamb (grass paddock raised) just doesn't have enough fat on it to survive a "rack in the oven" experience. Hogget & mutton is fine. This may be your problem too?

So for lamb I would cleave the rack into individual ribs and BBQ on medium-high till the surface has crisped (typically twice as long as a similar beef cut). All the fat should have run. Most people I know don't like eating visible lamb fat

I lightly coat the cut meat surface with oil just before placing on BBQ to ensure an instant sear. You want the lamb to crisp without drying out

If using a wood fired BBQ drop a bunch of fresh lavender (leaf and flowers) under the grill to slightly smoke the lamb